# Mixing many clauses and phrases immediately after conjunctions

Tags: grammar, phrases, commas, conjunctions, clauses

Let’s say I am compounding a sentence from the two sentences:

- A: I do fairly well in that class to show no concern
- B: I would appreciate some flexibility

with the conjuction *but*.

However, I want to spice up Sentence B by adding introductory phrases 
and/or clauses to the sentence.

- Case A:

  If I want to add the introductory phrases and clauses, *after all*,
  *since class is important*, and *if there is such a possibility*,
  to Sentence B in that order, what would be the correct way to do
  it?
- Case B:

  If I want to add the introductory phrases and clauses, *expectantly*
  and *as the university would discourage such behavior on your
  part*, to Sentence B in that order, what would be the correct way
  to do it?
- Case C:

  If I want to add only introductory phrases, such as *deeply* and
  *sincerely*, to Sentence B in that order, what would be the correct
  way to do it?
- Case D:

  If I want to add only introductory clauses, such as *because the
  university would discourage it* and *if there is such a possibility*,
  to Sentence B in that order, what would be the correct way to do
  it?

---

**Note**: This is regarding punctuation — commas.

Comment: It's pulled from a context. Sentence A and Sentence B are required to be compounded

Comment: The correct way would be to string them together inserting commas where necessary.   Case A: *I do fairly well in that class in showing no concern but after all, since class is so important, I would appreciate some flexibility- if there is such a possibility.*